# Photoshop cs5 weird move layer problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I updated my Photoshop to 12.0.4 and having problem when I try to move a layer with mouse even I disable 'snap'. There is no problem if I try to move with keyboard. DO you have any idea how to fix this problem? I tried to show my problem in this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sn2lYNl59bI

[image]

Comment: That is one weird problem. Sorry I can't be of help.

Comment: I couldnt find a solution to that too. Using ctrl+t to move.

Comment: The layer isn't locked, is it?

Comment: no, itsnt, check it.

Comment: Low RAM? A weird possibility.

Comment: I have 4gb ram in computer. Cs4 works good.

Comment: Uhm... Ghosts??

Comment: search this layer in your layer palate might me its having some other layer active on top of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Mac. The problem was iCopy app in the taskbar. I unchecked Capture Mouse Drags in the Preferences and problem was solved.